# how to set spark conf for pyspark standalone ipython notebook

Tags: apache-spark

I am running spark stand alone and starting pyspark from the command line so it opens an ipython notebook.  Here is how I start pyspark:

```
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook" /usr/local/src/spark/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/pyspark
```

Ipython notebook opens in my browser and there is already an SQLContext sc that I can start using.  However, I need to set a conf for the SparkContext.

```
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Cloudant Spark")
conf.set("jsonstore.rdd.schemaSampleSize", -1)

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
```

However, sc already exists so it won't let me create another one.  I tried an `sc.stop()` first but that gives me an error when I try to use the new sqlContext.

My questions are:
1. How can I set the conf?
2. Is there a better/different way of connecting an Ipython notebook to pyspark standalone?

Comment: have you tried spark-defaults.conf?

Comment: yes, but I don't see it after restarting pyspark and looking in pysparkshell application UI.  I put the following in spark-defaults.conf  jsonstore.rdd.schemaSampleSize     -1

Comment: Replace the SparkContext line by this :- sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf = conf)